# Which Virtual machine to install on Ubuntu Server for use as Media Player?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I'm currently running Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS (on an Intel E3300).
This connects to my TV via a HDMI port on a nVIDIA GeForce 9300GS.
Looking for a way install a Desktop on this machine as a VM so that I can easily remove or replace the Desktop and ensure it doesn't interfere with the operation of the server.
My concern is the as I need to playback Full-HD video.

Will a VM give the guest machine (probably Ubuntu Desktop) sufficient hardware access to allow it use the nVIDIA drivers? (No X11 installed on the Host.)

Or do I **have to** install the nVIDIA drivers on the Host machine? (AFAIK: that means install X11 first)

Answer (score 1):

In order for Full-HD playback to work correctly you need a dual core system with (I recommend) at least 4 gigs of RAM.  This means that a VM isn't the best road to go.  If you are wanting to have the server continue to do it's operation but still have access to the Media playback then you can [install the ubuntu desktop GUI](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-gui-in-ubuntu-server.html), and then use the gui to run the media.  I suggest using [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) which is a lightweight yet powerful media player system.